# How to implement start, stop and error methods in play framework(2.5.x)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, application-lifecycle

I am very new to play framework. I am trying to do something when my application will start and also do something when application will stop. I started searching for the entry and finish points and found out that in the **2.0** documentation there is ScalaGlobal where i can override the onStart, onStop and onError methods and do something inside it. **For example:**

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application has started")
  }  

  override def onStop(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Application shutdown...")
  }  

}
```

This code works fine for me in scala. But it is deprecated. 
But i could't find anything like that in **2.5.x** documentation. Is there any methods to access the **Start** and **Stop** points of an application in play framework??

1. ***How can i access the lifecycle methods in play framework??***

**EDIT:** **Is there any callbacks in play framework where any request will go through that method and then to others when certain methods are called like global ajax event handlers ??**

Answer (score 1):

To replace `onStart` method you need to define EagerBindings in new module: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings

To replace `onStop` method you need to register some code on stop hook:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Stopping/cleaning-up

To replace `onError` you need to define own error handler and add proper configuration in application.conf:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaErrorHandling

More information about migration to Play 2.5.x:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/GlobalSettings

Comment: I saw the links you have given but i don't know why it looked very complex to me.. The previous Global Settings were easy enough because it was like the activity lifecycle of android as i was an android developer. Is there any other simple example where the eager bindings, error handing or stoppings are nicely illustrated like how it works in detail ??

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know exact examples. All presented mechanisms are based on `dependency injection` and it should be a start for further research https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=play%20dependency%20injection

Answer (score -1):

You need to follow the source code of Play : [image: Comment in Play code]

You can do something in *Global.java* when the application starts or shuts down like this : [image: Global.java]